# create a private repository from an open source project

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

I have to create custom developments of an open source project on a public repository, say public-a.

The way I've done it so far is quite painful:

- created the private repository private-b and a branch "dev"
- copy pasted the files from public and commit on dev (maybe this was the initial error?)
- create some new files that are not in public-a and commit them on private-b/dev
- now I want to pull updates from public-a from within private-b folder:

  - `git remote add public-a https://....`
  - `git pull --rebase public-a master`
  - `git status`

    - to see the conflicts.. but in practice I just want to get the new version of the public files
  - for each conflict: `git checkout public-a master path/to/file/with/conflict`
  - `git add .`
  - `git --rebase continue`
  - `git commit -m "merges"`
  - `git push -u origin dev`

This is already painful, but now here is the most painful part:

```
! [rejected]        dev -> dev (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://../private-a.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

At this point I have to pull from the private one, and basically I have to reapply all the commits from the newest to the oldest of the public repo. I did that by skipping them all:

- `git pull --rebase`
- for each commit of the public repo: `git --rebase -skip`
- when there's nothing more to skip: `git push -u origin dev`

It seems to me this has worked:

- I have the latest files from the public-a and kept the private files (they are different files, private-b will never modify a file present also on public-a)

But this can't be right, what's the correct way of doing: "private repo which should copy files from a public one and create some new files which are never the same as the public one (I always have to get the updated public version of files in common between the two projects)"

Comment: why dont you just fork the public repo and then change your repo to private?

Comment: It is a private repository managed by another company, they can only create empty repositories

Comment: "copy pasted the files from public and commit on dev (maybe this was the initial error?)" - Yes, it sounds like it. It's not clear, but should the private repo be an exact clone of the public one?

Comment: every file in the public repo is the same in the private one, the private one has some additional files. So yes you can start from an exact clone, then add the extra files. Then from time to time I need to update the common file from the public repo